# How to get the proper output while appending find,ls and grep together?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, find

I wrote the command like

```
find /path -daystart -mtime 0 | ls -lh -- $(grep -i "cmac*") | awk '{print $6,$7,$9,$8,$5}'
```

It gives me the output *if any file is processed in that dir (path)* i.e file was processed when you execute that command.

```
date   filename   timestamp space
nov 1 cmac1234.txt 10:31 2.3M
```

It gives the following output when there is no files in the path stating with CMAC

```
Total Ok
....archive 
....inprogress
```

I don't want the archive or inprogress details, I just want if there is no files it will return null/blank. can you help me on this please.

NOTE: I want to fetch the file which either may be in /path dir or archive or inprogress dir.

Comment: Code which isn't doing what you want is a very poor way to explain what you *do* want.  What is the `grep` there supposed to achieve?  Whatever it is, it's probably not doing what you think.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do the thing you want:

```
find /path -daystart -mtime 0 -type f -iname "cmac*" -exec ls -lh {}\; |
  awk '{print $6,$7,$9,$8,$5}'
```

Comment: should the -name option be replaced by -iname (case-insensitive name) as the command in the question use grep -i

Answer (score 0):

Thanks webb, but it seems it was also not giving me the required output.

But I get the proper output by using below command.

find /path -daystart -mtime 0 -iname "cmac*" -ls | awk '{required fields}'

Thx,
Janaranjan